# jQuery click event on iPad not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, coffeescript

The click event should work fine:

```
  subMenu = $(".sub-menu")
  //....
  subMenu.show()
  $("a.mobile").click (e) ->
      menuContainer.toggle()
      e.preventDefault()
```

This should toggle the menu on click/tap. The weird thing is that it does it just fine for the first open and close.
Starting with the second time, to open, I have to click "a.mobile" twice. 
I've tried bind, and a bunch of other options. The CSS is actually displaying the link as it were hovered when it's not double-tapped.

Comment: This isn't an answer as such, but perhaps using [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html) could handle the proper iPad events?

Comment: Okay, I'll try to make a JSfiddle for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about .click() function, however i use .on('click') for handle events on my application and it works everywhere (including `IPads`). Nevertheless as suggested by the comments, perhaps there is something elsewhere preventing the click to work as you expect.